# JQuery validator - change response colour

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

I am using the JQuery validator plugin.  I have a submit handler like the following:

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/process.php",
        data: {
            'emailAddress': $("#emailAddress").val(),
        },
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function (response) {
            if(response[1] == 'Rejected'){
                $('#spanOne').addClass('red');
            }
            if(response[1] == 'Approved'){
               $('#spanOne').addClass('green');
            }
            if(response[3] == 'Rejected'){
               $('#spanTwo').addClass('red');
            }
            if(response[3] == 'Approved'){
               $('#spanTwo').addClass('green');
            }

            if(response[0] == 'F'){
                $('#spanOne').html('Your email has been ' + response[1]);
            }
            else{
                $('#spanOne').html(response[0] + ' has been ' + response[1]);
            }
            if(response[2] == 'F'){
                $('#spanTwo').html('Your mobile number has been ' + response[3]);
            }
            else{
                $('#spanTwo').html(response[2] + ' has been ' + response[3]);
            }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Now the first problem is that my done function seems messy to me.  Essentially, I havnt posted all the code, but my response is in the form of the following:

```
["F", "Rejected", "07364928374", "Approved", "ABC123"]
```

Basically, if position 1 is Rejected, I need spanOne to be red, otherwise it should be green.  Same applies to position 3.

I also have a invalidHandler which does a similar thing to the above.  It kind of works, if I enter an invalid email it displays red.  However, if I then submit a valid email, although it says Approved, it stays red.  So it seems like the done function is not updating?  In essence, it only really seems to work on the first submit.

How can I improve this to make it work all the time?

Thanks

Comment: Please show your HTML also!

Answer (score 0):

By your description, I guess you are adding a `red` class when you submit invalid data, but you don't remove it when you submit again. So even if the `green` class has been added, the `red` class is still there and may override it.

Check your email field 2nd time when you submit. Does it have both `red` and `green` classes? If so, add the following on the very top of `done` callback:

`$('#spanOne, #spanTwo').removeClass('red green')`